# How to completely silence the other party in a call on iOS

Tags: ios, call

Is there a way to completely silence the person on the other end of the call in iOS?

It appears that lowering the volume while a call is in progress doesn't silence the speaker completely, unlike when a call is not in progress.

[image: Call in progress] [image: Call not in progress]

Is there a way to silence the other party completely in the call?

Comment: This may not be considered for an answer, so posting as a comment. As far as I know this is by design in iOS (but not documented publicly). This may be so keeping usability in mind, so that user doesn't accidentally turn off the volume completely when in a call.

Comment: It also follows the functionality of regular (desk) phones where you can mute a call (they can't hear you), but you can't silence them.  This is how phones have always operated.

Comment: @NimeshNeema this makes sense, that’s what I’ve always figured as well. I’m wondering if there might be an Accessibility feature to disable it somehow.

Comment: @Allan wow, that's quite interesting! I never knew that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One to completely silence the other caller is to plug in a headphone auxiliary audio cable. You may need one with an inline mic such as [this one](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/headphone_accessories/quietcomfort-25-headphones-inline-mic-remote-apple-devices.html). This tricks iOS into thinking that there is an external output device and reroutes the output audio virtually into nothingness. The microphone is also switched to use the external microphone.